# Find the expectations of X under each of the following hypotheses.

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, expected-value

I've been stuck on this question for quite a while now. I was wondering what distributions each of these cases follow and how to solve. Any help would be much appreciated!

In an investigation into animal behaviour, rats have to choose between three similar doors, one of which is 'correct'. Correct choice is rewarded by food and incorrect choice is punished by a slight electric shock. If an incorrect choice is made, the rat is returned to the starting point and chooses again, this continuing until the correct door is chosen. The random variable X is the serial number of the trial on which the correct response is made, thus taking values 1,2,3,...

Find the expectations of X under each of the following hypotheses:

(a) Each door is equally likely to be chosen on each trial and all trials are mutually independent.
(b) At each trial the rat chooses with equal probability between doors which have not so far been tried, no choice ever being repeated.
(c) The rat never chooses the same door on two successive trials, but otherwise chooses at random with equal probability.

Comment: What are your thoughts?  Pick one of the cases and try.  Write out the probability that success occurs on the first trial (Hint:  that's the same for all three cases).  Now what's the probability that success occurs on the second trial?  The third?

Comment: I worked out for a. that it is 3 just due to the fact that the probability is the same for each trial. For part b I worked out the answer as 2 by doing 1/3+2/3+1 however I wasn't sure what distribution this is and it was more of a guess. In part c I didn't have a clue even where to start.

Comment: $3$ is correct for the first one.  For the second, it is impossible that the rat needs more than three attempts, so just write it out.  (your answer is correct but this way you'll be sure). For the third, follow the suggestion I gave in the first comment.

Comment: I have tried this but because the rat could keep choosing the same doors I wasn't sure how many trials it would actually get for the rat to find the correct door if you get what I mean? Not very good at wording my questions haha

Comment: Yes, in case three it is possible that the game can go on a long time.  that's true for the first case as well.  Hint:  after the first trial, what is the probability of success on each successive trial?

Comment: After the first trial the probability goes down to 1/2 for every successive trial. So my guess is the answer is 1/3 + 4*(1/2) = 7/3. I got the 4 as it will take 4 rounds to try every door?

Comment: Don't guess.  If the rat fails on the first trial, he is now tossing a fair coin.  What's the expected number of trials it takes to get $H$ from a fair coin?

Comment: The expected number of coin flips is 2. However what is confusing me is because the doors change due to the rat not picking the same door in succession does that effect the number of trials until the rat picks the correct door in the end? If not the answer would be 3 then.

Comment: $2$ is right.  Yes you are switching fair coins but each time it is still a fair coin.

Comment: Ok perfect, thank you

Comment: Add your thoughts in the post itself, not in comments. See https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For $(a)$, $X$ has geometric distribution with parameter $\frac13$, that is, $\mathbb P(X=k)=(1-p)^{k-1}p$ for $k=1,2,\ldots$. Hence
$$
\mathbb E[X] = \sum_{k=1}^\infty k\cdot\mathbb P(X=k) = \sum_{k=1}^\infty k\left(1-\frac13\right)^{k-1}\frac13 = \frac 1{1/3} = 3.
$$

For $(b)$, it is clear that
$$
\mathbb P(X=k) = \begin{cases}
\frac13,& k=1\\
\frac16,& k=2\\
\frac12,& k=3,
\end{cases}
$$
and so
$$
\mathbb E[X] = 1\cdot\frac13 + 2\cdot\frac16 + 3\cdot\frac12 = \frac{13}6.
$$

For $(c)$, clearly $\mathbb P(X=1)=\frac13$, and taking into account the fact that $\{X=k\}$ means that there were $k-1$ failures, we have $\mathbb P(X=k) = \frac23\left(\frac12\right)^{k-1}$. The first failure took place with probability $1-\frac13$, the rest of the failures took place with probability $\frac12$, and the success took place with probability $\frac12$. The expectation is thus
$$
\mathbb E[X] = 1\cdot\frac13 + \sum_{k=2}^\infty k\cdot \frac23\left(\frac12\right)^{k-1} = \frac73.
$$

Comment: How do you solve a geometric distribution? (the sum of k*(2/3)(1/2)^(k-1)) Sorry if I am being dim, I haven't done stats in years!

Comment: Recall that for $x\in\mathbb R$ with $|x|<1$, $$\sum_{k=0}^\infty x^k = \frac1{1-x}. $$ Differentiating both sides yields
$$
\sum_{k=0}^\infty (k+1)x^k = \frac1{(1-x)^2}.
$$
From there you should be able to derive the desired result.